# Expo app Infinite Refreshing then it crashes - Expo React Native

Tags: android, react-native, expo, mobile-application

I got this problem since weeks on expo projects.
At first, I hadn’t give attention to this but now it’s beginning to be annoying!

it make multiple refresh like CMD+R Android device, then the app just crashes or freezes.

Here is the console :

[image]

Does anyone have a solution ?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I too am facing the same problem from last 3 months. I posted a [question](https://forums.expo.io/t/infinite-building-javascript-bundle-error/49816) on Expo Forums regarding this but it is closed now.

Comment: Did you try removing **Expo** , and **Your project** from the Overview screen? If not click the Overview button  (the third button below/in below your screen.) Then remove **Expo** and **Your project** then open the app again.